# Hand built clang cannot find implicitly linked static library in Xcode default toolchain

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gcc, clang

As part of a research project I'm trying to use clang 6.0.1 with Xcode 9.4.1. I've built and installed clang in a custom location (/opt/llvm-6_0_1/clang). I wrote a simple xcplugin compiler specification to integrate my clang version with Xcode.

Now I can open projects in Xcode, select my proxy compiler and use it to build instead of Apple's default clang.

There were some minor additions that I had to make to the xcplugin's xcspec file to get this to work that probably won't be interesting to most people, so I won't provide the details here unless asked.

This all works with most of the projects I've played with, but I'm running into an odd problem where an implicitly linked static library cannot be found by my copy of clang. Specifically I get this error:

```
ld: file not found: /opt/llvm-6_0_1/clang/Toolchains/LLVM6.0.1.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_macosx.a
clang-6.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Note that the libarclite_macosx.a file is not explicitly included by the Xcode project. I figured it must be implicitly included, perhaps because this project enables ARC?

After pouring over the Xcode generated link command line (it's complex) I decided to look at the MyProject__dependency_info.dat file, which is passed in via the -dependency_info option. Apparently this data file (the path is defined as env var LD_DEPENDENCY_INFO_FILE) is created during the linking process, not as an input to the linker. Perhaps it exists because of a hack workaround using symlinks that I used to get a link to work (described at the end).

In any case the format appears to be binary, but I was able to see a text reference to libarclite_macosx.a in the file:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_macosx.a
```

After enabling the -Xlinker -v option I could see that my built clang was not searching the default toolchain lib or arc paths so I added them:

```
-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib
-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc
```

Now I can see the search paths in the verbose output, but clang still cannot find the library:

```
Library search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc
```

I've tried adding the paths to the frameworks search paths. I also tried defining the various link path env vars. Nothing has worked.

To try to get a sense of what clang is actually doing, I used fs_usage while getting the link error:

```
sudo fs_usage -e -w -f filesys | grep "lib/arc"

14:11:00.461965  stat64                 [  2]           /opt/llvm-6_0_1/clang/Toolchains/LLVM6.0.1.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                                                              0.000006   ld.1421614
14:11:00.461968  stat64                 [  2]           /opt/llvm-6_0_1/clang/Toolchains/LLVM6.0.1.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                                                              0.000002   ld.1421614
```

Clearly clang really wants to look for this file in the installed location, not the location indicated in the -dependency_info, nor in the search paths that I'm providing.

At this stage the only way I can get a build to work is to add a symlink to Xcode's "arc" directory to my installed clang lib directory. That "works", but is fragile and nasty.

Any thoughts as to how how I can get clang find the static library where it actually lives?